# Problem displaying image from url with Fancybox

Tags: image, cakephp, fancybox

I've stored all my images in database (Mysql), but when I whant to see that image with Fancybox, it display only the binary data, not the image.

My code:

```
<a href="/controller/action/id" class="group" rel="fancy">
    <img src="/controller/action/id/thumb" />
</a>
```

For url "/controller/action/id" I use this code to return the image:

```
header("Content-type: {$image['Image']['image_type']}");
echo $image['Image'][ $size ];
```

I use CakePHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nedd to specify 'type': 'image'.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.fancybox({
            'type':'image'
        });
```

This solved my problem.